# use python "re" to get sub string's position

Tags: python, regex

Here is a of string combined by random 0,1,like

```
number='111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111'
```

How to use python's re to get all the "1*..." and their position?

Here is mine:

```
re.compile(r"1+").findall(number)
```

And just get the "1..." ,i have to do more work to get it's position

all of "1..." and it's start and end position

Answer (score 5):

Use `match.span()`:

```
import re

number = '111111111111111111111111000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111'
for m in re.finditer(r'1+', number):
    print m.span()
```

This prints the starting and ending positions of each run of ones:

```
(0, 24)
(57, 81)
```

`m.group(0)` will give you the match as a string.